# VBA simplification - copy dataset between worksheets based on a result in a specific cell

Tags: vba, if-statement, resultset

In the model I am building I want to copy datasets from one worksheet to another based on a result in a 3rd worksheet.

I got to the code below. It works but takes way too much time for the task at hand.

Could anyone help me out and simplify it?

```
Sub RefreshDataSet()

Dim dataset1 As Range, dataset2 As Range, dataset3 As Range, dataset4 As Range, dataset5 As Range, rgdestinantion As Range

Set dataset1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_files").Range("A:AK")
Set dataset2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_files").Range("AL:CA")
Set dataset3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_files").Range("CB:DP")
Set dataset4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_files").Range("DQ:FG")
Set dataset5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_files").Range("FH:HB")

Set rgdestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Export").Range("A1")

Sheets("Data_Export").Cells.Clear

Set name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results").Range("D3")


If name = "EUR CLO1" Then

    Set rgdestination = rgdestination.Resize(dataset1.Rows.Count, dataset1.Columns.Count)
    rgdestination.Value = dataset1.Value

ElseIf name = "EUR CLO2" Then

    Set rgdestination = rgdestination.Resize(dataset2.Rows.Count, dataset2.Columns.Count)
    rgdestination.Value = dataset2.Value

ElseIf name = "EUR CLO3" Then
    
    Set rgdestination = rgdestination.Resize(dataset3.Rows.Count, dataset3.Columns.Count)
    rgdestination.Value = dataset3.Value

ElseIf name = "EUR CLO4" Then

    Set rgdestination = rgdestination.Resize(dataset4.Rows.Count, dataset4.Columns.Count)
    rgdestination.Value = dataset4.Value

ElseIf name = "EUR CLO5" Then

    Set rgdestination = rgdestination.Resize(dataset5.Rows.Count, dataset5.Columns.Count)
    rgdestination.Value = dataset5.Value

End If

End Sub
```

Thanks,

I tried multiple things, already. I am very happy that I got something to work. Not a vba expert in here at all. Grateful for any tips.

Comment: We need more context since *takes way too much time* (vague by the way) depends on how often this code is triggered. Every row of a 1 million row worksheet?

Comment: Try avoiding `Set` calls: `rgdestination.Resize(dataset1.Rows.Count, dataset1.Columns.Count).Value = dataset1.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Consider refactoring to only assign dataset ranges when needed and to avoid `Resize` calls for direct value assignment especially in cases of large ranges. Also turn off the UI application settings of `ScreenUpdating` and `Calculation`.

```vb
Sub RefreshDataSet()
On Error Goto ErrHandle
    Dim dataset1 As Range, dataset2 As Range, dataset3 As Range, dataset4 As Range, dataset5 As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = False

    ' CLEAN OUT DATA
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Export").Cells.Clear

    ' CONDITIONALLY POPULATE DATA
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Export")    
        Select Case ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results").Range("D3")
            Case "EUR CLO1"
            Set dataset1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_files").Range("A:AK")
            .Cells(dataset1.Rows.Count, dataset1.Columns.Count).Value = dataset1.Value

            Case "EUR CLO2" 
            Set dataset2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_files").Range("AL:CA")
            .Cells(dataset2.Rows.Count, dataset2.Columns.Count).Value = dataset2.Value

            Case "EUR CLO3"
            Set dataset3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_files").Range("CB:DP")
            .Cells(dataset3.Rows.Count, dataset3.Columns.Count).Value = dataset3.Value

            Case "EUR CLO4"
            Set dataset4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_files").Range("DQ:FG")
            .Cells(dataset4.Rows.Count, dataset4.Columns.Count).Value = dataset4.Value 

            Case "EUR CLO5"
            Set dataset5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_files").Range("FH:HB")
            .Cells(dataset5.Rows.Count, dataset5.Columns.Count).Value = dataset5.Value
        End Select
    End With

ExitHandle:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    Msgbox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Sadly your code didn't work but your comment on looking into a numbers of rows worked. I now limited my range to only 400 rows per range, as it will never exceed this amount and my code copies datasets almost instantly.

Comment: What error raised with this code?

Comment: No error, the code ran just fine. the thing is for some reason it didnt do anything, even though when I look at it it makes sense....